# Calculate a formula in Reverse Polish Notation

Tags: polish-notation

I hope I'm writing this post in correct forum. I've got a equation `-11*2*(-1)*3` which i transferred into RPN -> `11,2,*,1,-,*,3,*,-`. And here I have problem with resolving it:

```
11*2 = 22
22-1= 21
22*what = ?
```

what should i multiply by in last equation (I've got nothing left on stack) ...?

Comment: So assuming what You have written it should be -11,2,* ...

Comment: Okey, I understand. Thank You ;). I need to change my program a little bit :(

Comment: If I've resolved your question, maybe I'll turn my comment into an answer so you can accept it, and the question doesn't remain open.

Comment: Sure, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion in the question about whether $−$ is a binary or unary operator. Certainly you shouldn't be doing any subtraction when computing this product...

I would translate this expression (it's not an equation, there's no equals sign) as $$−11,2,*,−1,*,3,*,$$ or if you require that we use only positive integers and interpret $−$ as a unary negation operator, $$11,−,2,*,1,−,*,3,*.$$

Comment: Perhaps, to disambiguate, we should use $-$ for the binary operator and $^-$ for the unary one, like $11,{}^-,2,*,1,{}^-,*,3,*$.

Comment: The Hewlett-Packard HP11C RPN scientific calculator (the best calculator ever) had a CHS (change sign) key equivalent to the $\pm$ key on algebraic calculators so if one wished only to enter non-negative numbers one could express it as $11,\pm$.